# Some queries about device compatibility on a Mac

Tags: usb, sd-card

1. Do normal card readers [like these](http://www.flipkart.com/search?q=card%20reader&as=on&as-show=off&otracker=start&as-pos=1_q_card%20reade) detect automatically on a Mac
   or a separate app should be installed ?
2. Do DSLR camera's SD card detect on a mac just like a normal SD card
   or should I install a separate app for it ?
3. Will the Mac detect my Motorola G when I connect it via USB ?
4. If files from Mac are copied to pendrive, will Windows detect the files from the pen drive ? Or should I format my pendrive to use it on a windows laptop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Just a side note: all these answers could have been very easily found by just typing them into Google.*

1. The majority of card readers will just work out of the box on OS X. If they don't you either need to install a driver or it just isn't compatible. Big brands like Kingston or Sandisk will work 99% of the time.
2. If you're using SD cards there really is no difference if you're using it on a DSLR or a Mac. The storage medium itself is what is taken into account when using it. You shouldn't need to install an app for hardware like SD cards.
3. It should connect out of the box. But this question isn't really related to Apple since it's really dependant of the smartphone your using and what software or drivers the manufacturer provides
4. To have cross platform read/write support on your pendrive on both OS X and Windows the drive needs to be formatted as FAT32 or NTFS/ExFat.
   ExFat is only supported starting from OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) and NFTS has no out of the box write compatibility on OS X.

Comment: Does windows and Mac support `NTFS/ExFat` type of format for pendrives ?

Comment: I got mixed answers in Google, So was forced to ask here

Comment: @OSXYosemite All current versions of Windows support both NTFS and ExFat. Using NTFS you won't be able to write to it using OS X, since OS X has no native write support for NTFS (there are some packages on brew for this though). ExFat has read and write on all Windows versions and Snow Leopard. If you are using a version of OS X higher than 10.6 ExFat is what I'd go with.